# How to save numpy array of images dataset?

Tags: python, arrays, image, tensorflow2.0, conv-neural-network

I am using my own dataset to train CNN. I have converted the images to a numpy array and the labels to another array. How can I save them to be able to load the data when I need to train the model? I tried pickle, but the data size is too big for it.

I am using `python3.7` and `tensorflow 2.1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to do so, one is to save it as csv file.

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```

For a more efficient way, you can use HDF5 with h5py.

```
import h5py
h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=a)
```

Comment: Is it going to save each for labels and images separate or combiened?

Comment: Can you give more ways. Thanks

Comment: It saves them combined, is there anything specific you want to achieve and need a different ways than the described one?

Comment: the images array is 4d. I want to load it whenever I want to train the model. Is this way efficient.

Comment: I added another way for more efficient data storing.